# Is it required to use IdentityDbContext for JWT authentication under .NET Core 2.0 and EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm playing around with the login procedures under .NET Core and I noticed that when I follow the guides and use `IdentityDbContext` with `IdentityUser` I get a bunch of tables automagically in the database (e.g. *AspNetUsers*, *AspNetUserClaims* etc.).

While it's nice, I wonder if it's very wrong to use the less magical `DbContext` instead and create my own schema for user and role management. I prefer to "kill my own food" in order to understand how the security works and I dislike using tools and frameworks that I don't understand the bolts and nuts of. ("It just works like that" leads often to problems when it stops working as supposed to.)

Is the *Identity* part in `IdentityDbContext`, `IdentityUser` etc. just a convenience thingy or are those supposed to be used?

The tech stack I'll be targeting is .NET Core 2.0 and JWT authentication. Of course, the model is supposed to be managed in the DB by EF.

Please forgive if the question is stupidly asked. I'm a rookie on the security and might be barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not required to use these classes. They are a tested convenience implementation to fit most common use cases but you can replace or customise aspects of the Identity stack.

The identity stack has the following components:

- Managers: `UserManager`, `RoleManager` and similar classes are used from within the Application to perform the necessary "business" operations with the data. Although you can replace them with custom implementations, it is hardly ever necessary.
- Stores: `UserStore`, `RoleStore` and similar are used to perform core data operations on the types they manage. You can provide custom implementations to replace the storage mechanism used. The provided stores use entity framework to perform data operations on the managed types. You can replace these to implement other store types. if you were to store user data as documents in ElasticSearch, this would be the interfaces to implement.
- Store data types: `IdentityUser`, `IdentityRole` etc are the default entity types that hold information about the user/role/claim/.. These types can be subclassed to extend them or you can use different classes if you wish. For example, if you were to store in ElasticSearch, you could reuse these types to avoid creating custom ones to hold user data. The default stores (entity framework) are built to handle subclasses should you wish to store custom information with them. But you do not have to and can use any classes you like as long as you implement a custom store that knows how to use them and there is at least an `Id` and a `UserName` property on them.

For more information about customisation options, refer to the [Custom storage providers for ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers) documentation page.

Comment: That answers my question. However, I still have a few issues thar confuse me. (1) I want my `Id` to be a guid. Can I just `new` it over the default string type without creating damage to the convenience of the classes? (2) I was expecting the class `IdentityUser` to have a reference to `IdentityRole` and a list of claims but as far I saw, intellisense didn't present anything like that. Am I missing something?

Comment: (1) The `IdentityUser` is a subclass of `IdentityUser<TKey>` which you could use to customise the type of ID to be used. I do not know what the actual design decision was to use `string` by default but personally(!) I like it since it does not assume a store that is capable of auto-incrementing integers by default.

Comment: (2) The concerns in the stores are separated, so a store does not have to implement claims by default. The `UserManager` would then throw exceptions on claim operations and its `SupportsUserClaim` property would return false. A store may implement `IUserClaimStore<TUser>` if the application is to support claims.

Comment: As for (1), I'm used to the guid-ification of all IDs. How can one smoothly assign a random guid if the field type is string? I've seen there's an option in FluidApi to autogenerate values on addition but that won't do much good in the case of string, will it? What strategy of assigning values as IDs would you recommend for `IdentityUser` type?

Comment: Where is the user manager located? (Or, possibly, where should it be implemented?) Sorry if the question is dumb - just trying to get my bearings around this thing.

Comment: `IdentityUser` sets a new guid tostring'ed in its constructor. `UserManager` is an asp.net core provided type that you typically don't need to touch. I recommend looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/release/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core) to explore customisation options

Comment: Perfect! Now I can follow the trail of howtos. Definitely +1 for the follow-ups.Thanks!